# al meter elementos en una lista hace algo raro

Tags: python, python-3.x

quiero que un codigo compruebe una lista de 0 y 1 y seleccione solo los 1 y guarde en una lista este es el codigo que hice:

```
lista_1 = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
lista_2 = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
lista_3 = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
listas = [lista_1, lista_2, lista_3]
elemento_1 = []
for lista in listas:
    for elemento in lista:
        elemento = int(elemento)
        if elemento == 1:
            elemento_1.append(lista)
            elemento_1.append(elemento)
print(elemento_1)
```

y lo que me aparece es esto:
[[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], 1, [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], 1, [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], 1, [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], 1, [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], 1, [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], 1, [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], 1, [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], 1, [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], 1]

Comment: El resultado corresponde al código: estás haciendo `append()` tanto de la lista como del elemento. Elimina la línea que dice `elemento_1.append(lista)`

Comment: `unos = [x for lista in listas for x in lista if x == 1]`

Comment: lo que estás haciendo es, para cada elemento en cada lista, si el elemento es 1 agregá a la lista `elemento_1` la lista en la que aparece y luego el elemento (o sea un 1) con lo que tu lista `elemento_1` va a tener adentro `[ unaLista, 1, otraLista, 1,.... ]` que ques lo que querés hacer?